# Не работает фильтр ~filters.contact.Это автоответчик ,который должен писать только не контактам и только 1 раз.Повторного сообщения быть не должно

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

async def message_handler(client_obj, message_obj, text):
await asyncio.sleep(5)
await client_obj.read_history(message_obj.chat.id)

```
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await client_obj.send_chat_action(message_obj.chat.id, "typing")
        await asyncio.sleep(7)
        await client_obj.send_message(message_obj.chat.id, text)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        



    @app.on_message(filters.text & filters.private & ~filters.me & ~filters.contact & ~filters.bot)
    async def text_handler(client, message):
        if message.from_user.id not in sp_p:
            await message_handler(client, message, "Привет,я бот-защитник этого пользователя.Не пишите ему в лс!Из-за указаний пользователя ,я вынужден вас заблокировать.Для того ,чтобы связаться с Nex1n,пишите сюда => https://t.me/nex1n_bot")
            await app.block_user(message.chat.id)
        else:
            await message_handler(client, message, ".")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да,извините,я тут новичёк)У меня несколько проблем:
1.Юзербот не реагирует на фильтр contact
2.Юзербот не должен отправлять сообщения больше,чем 1 раз.